# SQL Server: how to remove leading 'A's from base64 string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, base64, xquery

I'm working on SQL Server and trying to create a single key combining data from `bigint` and `string` columns. To minimize the size of `bigint's` represented as strings I'm using Base 64 encoding. The problem is that the result includes leading 'A's meaning `base64` zeroes and it increases the size of the resulting field. What is the way to remove these leading `A` using `T-SQL` or `XQuery`?

Sample code:

```
DECLARE @binInput VARBINARY(MAX)
SET @binInput = CAST(123 AS VARBINARY(MAX))

SELECT CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@binInput"))', 'varchar(max)')
```

I have a resulting `AAAAew==` where I would prefer to see just `ew` because of the idea is to make the final string as short as it possible and base64 string should be shorter than base10.

**update 1**: as were suggested by Richard Boyce I tried to convert bigint to the equal string, but it gives null as a result of base64 conversion

```
declare @input bigint
declare @varInput nvarchar(max)
set @input = 123
set @varInput = cast(cast(@input as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max))
select CAST(N'' AS xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@varInput"))', 'varchar(max)')
```

**update 2**: the current solution is to get a base64binary string and to remove leading 'A's and trailing '='s. It's not perfect, so any suggestions are welcome. Actual code:

```
declare @input bigint
set @input = 1234567890
declare @output varchar(max)
set @output = (select cast(@input as varbinary(max)) for xml path(''),binary base64)
set @output = replace(ltrim(replace(@output,'A',' ')),' ','A') -- remove leading 'A's
set @output = replace(@output,'=','') -- remove trailing '='s
select @output
```

Comment: change "cast(cast(@input as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max))" to "cast(cast(@input as varchar(max)) as varbinary(max))"

Comment: still having 'null' as a result. The question was that when 123 is converted to a strings it takes three chars to represent the result because of it's 10 based. And when converting this to a base64 it should take only two characters. So it should be converted this way: bigint->binary->base64 string

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to remove leading "A's" from the encoded result look at preventing them in the first place.

You need to convert your number to a string before encoding.

Try this

```
DECLARE @binInput VARBINARY(MAX)
SET @binInput = CAST(CAST(123 AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS VARBINARY(MAX))

DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Result = CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@binInput"))', 'varchar(max)')

SELECT CAST(CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@Result"))', 'varbinary(max)') AS VARCHAR(MAX))
```

Note that when encoded "123" becomes "MTIz" not ew==

Comment: Ah, *now* I see what @Viacheslav is asking (I must be having a dumb day!) Of course, the AAAA isn't Base64 padding, the trailing '=' are, the A's are just the leading zeros encoded. Doh! Nice, simple, answer.

Comment: The problem is that '123' string a way bigger than 123 integer.

Comment: I tried to make bingint->binary->string as a source for base64 conversion, but it gives null

Comment: You can still use BigInt.  Just convert to string before encoding and the convert the string to BigInt after decoding

Answer (score 1):

Not wanting to leave an answer that doesn't answer the question, here's how to remove a number of leading A's from a string (but the answer @Richard gave is better):

```
DECLARE @VAL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'AAAA12345ABCD9876=='
SELECT SUBSTRING(@VAL,PATINDEX('%[^A]%',@VAL), LEN(@VAL))

----------------
12345ABCD9876==
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but using recursive operation seems to be time consuming here. I'm trying to find a way to avoid adding these 'A's in the beginning of the base64 string or at least to delete them without recursion

Comment: Actually 'A' in base64 means zero, 'B' - 1 and so on. So base64 'ABA' means 64 and 'BA' - too. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: This code seems to be a bit easier: select replace(ltrim(replace(@val,'A',' ')),' ','A')